# Virtual file system tree webservices and NFS

Tags: architecture, tree, nfs

We were thinking about building a virtual file system in SQL. 
There are several knowns ways of achieving file system like structures in SQL (Materialzed path, adjency lists ...).

After a while we thought of using NFS to store the directory/file structure and flat key value store to store custom attributes.

The directory/file structure  on NFS would store ids only.

```
Dxxxxx1
    Fxxxxx1
Dxxxxx2
    Fxxxxx1
    Fxxxxx2
    Fxxxxx3
```

And a Flat table looking like this:

```
Dxxxxx1: {'name': 'mydir A', ... }

Dxxxxx2: {'name': 'mydir B', ... }

Fxxxxx1: {'name': 'file A', size: '', ... }
```

We would benefit from symlinks, mountpoint and UNIX permissions.

What are the cons of such an architecture?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest one you might run into is speed issues with NFS. We learned here that NSF wasn't as reliable (random locking problems) and as fast as we needed. Do the volume/stress test before you commit to this architecture.